# Android Kotlin - set animation end / finish listener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

```
val anim = swipe.animate()
        .rotationBy((-30).toFloat())
        .setDuration(1000)
        .translationX((-swipe.left).toFloat())
        .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())

anim.start()
```

I need an animation finish listener, I tried:

```
anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {

    }

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

    }

    override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {

    }
})
```

but get this error

> Unresolved reference: setAnimationListener

How to do this right?

Comment: How about Animator.AnimationListener { ... } ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Root cause**

In [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) class, there is no method named `setAnimationListener`.

**Solution 1**

```
anim.withEndAction {
    // Your code logic goes here.
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
anim.setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
        // Your code logic goes here.
    }
})
```

**Note:** Remember to cancel the anim if users leave the screen while animation.

```
swipe.animate().cancel()
```